# how will this statement execute conditional operation in c?

Tags: c, operators, conditional-operator

i have conditional operator's statement and i have no idea how its works.
there are two questions:

**Question 1 :** what will the following statement do :

```
 quotient=(b==0)?0:(a/b) \\ here a,b,quotient is integer
```

**Question 2 :** Can preceding statement be written as follow ?

```
 quotient=(b)?(a/b):0;
```

***NOW MY QUESTION IS :***

**Question:1 ::** we do not know b's value then how can we check this condition(b==0)

**Question 2::** what (b) indicate ?

Comment: The variable `b` evaluates to itself and if non-zero evaluates to true, else is false.

Comment: Notice that the result of boolean operators *themselves*, including `==`, are of type *`int`* - `1` for true and `0` for false.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: "boolean operator" -> "relational operator", pretty please?

Comment: Actually, `==` is equality operator, not a relational operator...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala; Touche.

Comment: Of course I cannot edit it, but something like "those operators that yield a truth value in C will yield either `1` or `0`, of type `int`."

Comment: To start with, question 1 does not show a statement. And what's your problem you don't find in the conditional operator's documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try

```
int b = 0;
if (b) {
   printf("Hello World");
}
```

Does not print anything while :

```
int b = 1;
if (b) {
    printf("Hello World");
}
```

Prints `Hello World`. Why ? Because 0 is false and 1 is true.

If you do `quotient=(b)?(a/b):0;` it is interpreted to `is b true ?` or in other words `is b evaluated to 1` (while, again, [1 is true and 0 is false](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type#C,_C++,_Objective-C,_AWK))

Comment: Not just `1`, any number other than `0` is `true`. You should probably mention that. Because in OP's case `b` can be any number.

Answer (score 3):

The conditional check in the C ternary conditional operator is an implicit comparison to not-zero.

In other words

```
quotient = b ? a / b: 0;
```

is the same as

```
quotient = b != 0 ?  a / b : 0;
```

or the absurd

```
quotient = (b != 0) != 0 ?  a / b : 0;
```

This is consistent throughout C, e.g. in an `if`, a `for` stopping condition, a `while`, `&&`, `||`, &c.

Answer (score 1):

C did not originally have a Boolean type.  Conditionals are simply `int` values in C.  0 is false, and any other value is truthy.  If the type of `b` is `int`, or it can implicitly convert to `int`, then `(b) ? foo : bar` does the same thing as `(b == 0) ? bar : foo`.  (However, `b==0` will evaluate to 1 or 0, whereas `b` by itself might have other nonzero values that `if` or `?` consider truthy.)